# Right way to escape string after replacing quotes?

Tags: php, mysql

Is this the right way to escape a string just in case or I can insert string like this without additional escaping?

```
$filenamefordb = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9а-яА-Я_\.\-]/u', '', $filenamefordb);
$query = "INSERT INTO file SET filename='$filenamefordb";
```

I don't use mysqli_escape  because I also need name without any quotes in another place

Comment: Why not use the escaping functions provided by your MySQL API? Then you'll know it's right...

Comment: because I need filename without any others symbols

Comment: What good does randomly removing a bunch of characters do?  Aren't you just _silently breaking_ loads of possible input filenames? Why?

Comment: What does u mean in "silently breaking loads"?

Comment: Well I don't know, do I? We have no idea what your program does. But if your program stores the filenames of files that exist, then your simply removing various characters from those filenames in the DB means they will no longer be correct, and whatever your program does will be broken when you pull the filenames out again. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you escape the string using PDO?

```
<?php
    $conn = new PDO('sqlite:/home/lynn/music.sql3');

    /* Complex string */
    $string = "Co'mpl''ex \"st'\"ring";
    print "Unquoted string: $string\n";
    print "Quoted string: " . $conn->quote($string) . "\n";
?>
```

This will output

```
Unquoted string: Co'mpl''ex "st'"ring
Quoted string: 'Co''mpl''''ex "st''"ring'
```

Reference: 
http://php.net/manual/it/pdo.quote.php

Comment: because I also need string without quetes, just a-z and numbers ( I need it for another place)

Answer (score 0):

you can escape it with a generic php function:

```
$filenamefordb = mysql_escape_string ($filenamefordb);
$query = "INSERT INTO file SET filename='$filenamefordb";
```

Comment: To note: `mysql_` is deprecated.

Comment: I know about mysqli_escape but I need also a name without any special symbols

Comment: @x1site: You need to think about where that name comes from in the first place, and why it has "special symbols", and why you don't want them. You should probably reject them much further down your call stack.

Comment: because I can accept files with any file names, and change it as I need